# How can we map the drivers Rest/Stop points on PTV Vector Map

Tags: ptv-developer

We're builing a route optimzation web-based application in Reactjs. We use PTV vector maps and generate Polyline using PTV API. Now we also need to render DRIVER's Stop or Rest Points on the Vector.

My question is how can I get the Rest/Stop Points on specific route only and then render it on PTV vector Reactjs maps.

I did not get the proper API in the PTV documention about the Rest/Stop Points.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the coordinate of the points from a route and use start and stop coordinate from the POLYGON result, it is fairly easy to display it on a vector map.
[https://api.myptv.com/routing/v1/routes?waypoints=49.0133618,8.4277972&waypoints=48.8950289,8.6715602&results=POLYLINE&options[trafficMode]=AVERAGE&apiKey=XXX](https://api.myptv.com/routing/v1/routes?waypoints=49.0133618,8.4277972&waypoints=48.8950289,8.6715602&results=POLYLINE&options%5BtrafficMode%5D=AVERAGE&apiKey=XXX)

It depends on the client renderer you are using.
Here is a tutorial how to render additional contend with Leaflet on a vector map:
https://developer.myptv.com/en/resources/tutorials/map-rendering/vector-map-restrictions